# Android Espresso keeps running two tests concurrently?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-espresso, otto

So I have a few Espresso tests set up (under same test file) and I also have Otto which is registering and unregistering this fragment to ensure that there is only once instance of the fragment per app instance.

I noticed that some tests were failing because the app was trying to create another fragment even though we already had an instance of that fragment. After hiding some of the Otto registering/unregistering code, it seems as if Espresso is running two tests concurrently? The log messages were intertwined for two tests, showing that the fragment was being created for test One then another instance of the fragment was being created for test Two and then the fragment instance for test One was removed followed by the one for test Two. Is this expected behavior from Espresso?